# Why must I import both "image/color" and "image"?

Tags: go

I am just learning Go and wrote the following struct (`Image`) to implement the `image.Image` interface.

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "code.google.com/p/go-tour/pic"
)

type Image struct{}

func (img Image) ColorModel() color.Model {
    return color.RGBAModel
}

func (img Image) Bounds() image.Rectangle {
    return image.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
}

func (img Image) At(x, y int) color.Color {
    return color.RGBA{100, 100, 255, 255}   
}

func main() {
    m := Image{}
    pic.ShowImage(m)
}
```

If I just import `image/color` and not import `image`, `image.Rect` is undefined. Why? Shouldn't `image/color` already cover the methods and properties of `image`?

Also, if I change the function receivers from `(img Image)` to `(img *Image)`, an error arises:

```
Image does not implement image.Image (At method requires pointer receiver)
```

Why is that? Doesn't `(img *Image)` indicate a pointer receiver?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check out the [source for the `image` package](http://golang.org/src/pkg/image/) and its sub-packages, you will see that [`image/color` does not depend on `image`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/image/color/color.go) at all, so it never imports it.

[`image` does however import `image/color`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/image/image.go)

For the second part of your question, where you change all of the receivers to pointers, that means you should also be passing an Image pointer to `ShowImage`:

```
func main() {
    m := Image{}
    pic.ShowImage(&m)
}
```

Methods defined on a pointer receiver must be accessed on a pointer. But methods defined on just the struct can be accessed from a pointer or the value.

Here is some documentation explaining the difference between a pointer or a value receiver of a method:

1. [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#methods_on_values_or_pointers)
2. [Why do T and *T have different method sets?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#different_method_sets)